# Charts not exporting on PDF using maatwebsite/excel for Laravel

Tags: laravel, mpdf, maatwebsite-excel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Using the package maatwebsite/excel for Laravel I'm trying to export to PDF an XLSX that has a chart in it.

I can see the chart if I export as an xlsx file, but when exporting to PDF is not showing the chart.

I have tried with all the PDF Renderers:

- dompdf/dompdf
- mpdf/mpdf
- tecnickcom/tcpdf

Without any success.

Using AfterSheet I have manage to render to an external file the chart. But I can't manage to have the chart outputted to the PDF.

```php
// SecondSheet

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return  [
        AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
            $worksheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
            $chartNames = $worksheet->getChartNames();
            foreach ($chartNames as $chartName) {
                $chart = $worksheet->getChartByName($chartName);
                $chart->render(storage_path('app/' . $chartName . '.png'));
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

I'm exporting the file as:

```php
Excel::store(new TheReportExport($myCollection), $fileName, null, MaatwebsiteExcel::MPDF);
```

And `TheReportExport` file looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Exports\Sheets\FirstSheet;
use App\Exports\Sheets\SecondSheet;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeWriting;

class TheReportExport implements WithMultipleSheets, WithEvents
{
    private $data;
    public function __construct(Collection $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];
        $sheets[] = new FirstSheet($this->data);
        $sheets[] = new SecondSheet($this->data);
        return $sheets;
    }
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: One option will be to render the image using a separate package and include it manually into pdf.